# Clone Jira task

Tags: python, rest, jira

We have the name of the problem in the jira, for example TES-111

Create a clone of this task, remember its number. For example, TES-112
Move the new TES-112 task to another project, such as SUP. She will be assigned a number, for example, SUP-423. The condition is that in task SUP-423 it can be seen that it is cloning TES-112.
That is, in the web face, everything is simple, first Clone, then Move and select the project.

How do i get an issue:

```
url = f'{base_url}/issue/{issue_key}'
response = requests.request(
    "GET",
    url,
    headers=headers
    )

print(json.dumps(json.loads(response.text), sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(",", ": ")))
```

How I try to create a new one

```
url_2 = f'{base_url}/issue'
payload = response
response_2 = requests.request(
   "POST",
   url,
   data=payload,
   headers=headers
```

But I always get errors, and i dont know how to change payload correctly to fit this method.

I did not find API for "cloning". Apparently, it is necessary to memorize each task in full and restore it, but it is impossible to do this. Please tell me how to implement this in python. Perhaps there are more convenient ways.